# Triangle $ABC$ with $P$ and $Q$ on $AC$ and $AB,$ prove circumcenter of triangle is orthocenter of another

Tags: geometry

> An acute riangle $ABC$ has $P$ and $Q$ which lie on $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. If $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BPQ,$ prove the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle BPQ.$

I defined $X$ is the intersection of $QO$ with $BP,$ $Y$ is the intersection of $BO$ with $QO.$ $Z$ is the intersection of $PO$ and $QB.$

I have noticed that due to the angle conditions, we have $\triangle APB$ isosceles, and so we have $PO$ bisects $AB,$ because $AB$ is a chord of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC.$ So I proved that $PO$ is an altitude in $\triangle BPQ.$ However, from here I am not sure how to continue. I have attempted to angle chase on proving $\angle PBQ = \angle QOZ,$ which would prove $BXOZ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral which implies $QO$ is an altitude, implying the result. However, I am getting no where with this approach. I've also tried proving $\triangle QOZ \sim \triangle POX,$ but to no avail. May I have some help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: If anyone would like to know, I found this problem, it was from a post on this aops blog a few years ago: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c288875h1283745

Edit: also notice $P$ and $Q$ do not necessarily have to lie on segments $AC$ and $AB,$ so such a configuration is possible.

Comment: Please provide a figure : indeed, your property $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BPQ$ is not evident to fulfill : do you mean that this similarity is such that $A \leftrightarrow B, B  \leftrightarrow P,   C \leftrightarrow Q$ in this order ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Points $P$ and $Q$ need not lie on segment $AC$ and $AB$, then can also lie on lines $AC$ and $AB$.

Comment: How are defined $X$ and $Z$ in your proof attempt ?

Comment: Oh my, so sorry for not telling you. $X$ is the intersection of $QO$ with $BP,$ $Y$ is the intersection of $BO$ with $QO.$ $Z$ is the intersection of $PO$ and $QB.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine $X$ the point such that $QX' \perp BP.$ Then $\angle ZOX = 180^\circ-\angle A$ from cyclic quadrilateral $BX'OZ.$ Note $$\angle QOZ=90^\circ - \angle BQX = 90^\circ-(90^\circ - \angle PBQ) = \angle A,$$ proving collinearity with our new definition of $X.$ Since you have $PO \perp AB$ and $QP \perp BP,$ the result follows.